# Ionic WKWeabView breaks Template on iOS

Tags: ios, javascript, html

I was trying to publish my application on Apple Store, but they blocked it since UIWebView was detected. I found no “UIWebView” occurrences in the project, but the application is still being blocked by the Store.

I found on the Internet that I had to install WKWebView using the following command:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin install cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save
```

Then I had to fix the config.xml in the following way:

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

The application starts, but when I do a GET on a page and try to display the response I have the following result: https://imgur.com/a/uaBWZOf

The first card is static, while the others are dynamic: the static card is displayed correctly, while the dynamic ones are displayed only opening the side menu or clicking the filters. No chance to get the dynamic content on the opening of the page.
The code that generates dynamic content is correct since it runs correctly on Android side and on iOS side without WKWebView installed too.
Ionic version: 6.17.1
Cordova version: 7.1.0
Any idea of what could be what could cause the card problem and how to fix it?